# Make space between list line

Tags: javascript, css

So, I have a list of items which are displayed `inline-block`. What I'ld like is when you click on a cell, the lines under it go down. Problem is, simply adding a `margin-bottom` won't work, like showed with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Axiol/j93H5/).

See, the one which should be opened is left alone on her line. What I'd like is something like that:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: you need to explain what you need better, it is unclear what you want.

Comment: something along the lines of `li:nth-child(12)::after { display: block; }` maybe? Splitting into multiple lists would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, multiple lists was my first go, but, it does not work when it cames to responsive with line getting shorter. Sam, question edited, hope its more clear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default alignment of `inline-block` elements is `baseline`, meaning tall and short items will align the bottom of the text line. If you give the `<li>` elements `vertical-align: top`, i believe you get what you want;

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align: top; /* added */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j93H5/3/

Comment: I wasn't aware of the default alignement... Thank you, you sure saved my night a bit :)

Comment: you beat me to the publish but i got the first fiddle. up-voting this one for your ability to be concise. :)

Comment: @jakealbaugh hehe cheers. i +1'd yours too because its completely correct ;) Also, @Axiol just a sidenote: the vertical spacing you get between the items when using `baseline` is because the "text line" makes space for descenders (low hanging letters like "y" and "g"). I added a 4px top margin just like jake did to make up for it.

Comment: @xec Or we could just add the `vertical-align: top;` to the `.space` one, seems like it does it too. Anyway, thanks again for being concise :)

Comment: @Axiol Yes, because that's the item that's pushing the others it would work too, but I would still keep it on the `li` if I was you, let's say you wanted to animate the change for instance, compare http://jsfiddle.net/j93H5/8/ with http://jsfiddle.net/j93H5/9/ (issues when transitioning back)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add vertical alignment for your margin-bottom and then a margin-top to vertically space your `li`s:

```
vertical-align: top;
margin-top: 4px;
```

## http://jsfiddle.net/j93H5/1/

as @Bergi said, splitting into multiple lists is probably the least sloppy way to do this and most likely the more appropriate method, but we don't really know the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-elements to push elements out of the way:

```
li.space:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
}
```

[View jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j93H5/7/)